How to increase the stack depth of native code in hs_err_pid.log

There are only two layers of native code stack information in the hs_err_pid.log, making it difficult to pinpoint the issue

how to increase the stack depth of native code in the hs_err_pid.log ?

the follow code is my hs_err_pid.log, but only thirdy_party code here


Stack: [0x00007faf9f577000,0x00007faf9f678000],  sp=0x00007faf9f6737e0,  free space=1009k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so+0x1e8c85]  Taise damroset nantersetaphanteres neunsigned short, Long», falses thandte(unsigned long, unsigned long, faiss: sind16unt16, fais
s: :simd16uint16)+0x71
C  [libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so+0x1eaba0]  void faiss:: (anonymous namespace):: pq4_100p_qbs_fixed_scaler<faiss: :simd_handlers::HeapHandler<faiss:: CMin<unsigned false>,taiss::DummyScaler>(int,unsigned long, int, signed char const ensigned char const*, Paiss: Smaresult handlers: HeapHand erstairs: CMinsunsigned short, Longs, Talses, faiss: ummyScaler consts) [clone .isra.0]+0x103c
j  com.alibaba.lindorm.base.vectorcore.FlatIndex.getDistance(J[BIF[[B)Lcom/alibaba/lindorm/base/vectorcore/KnnResult;+0
j  com.alibaba.lindorm.base.vectorcore.FlatIndex.getDistance([BIF[[B)Lcom/alibaba/lindorm/base/vectorcore/KnnResult;+56



